# Running BLAST queries with BioPython

Tags: bioinformatics, biopython, sequences, blast

I would like to

1. BLAST several sequences
2. Retrieve the top 100 hits or so from each query
3. Pool the downloaded sequences
4. Remove duplicates

How I can do this in BioPython?

Answer (score 7):

```
 from Bio.Blast import NCBIWWW
    fasta_string = open("myfasta").read()
    result_handle = NCBIWWW.qblast("blastn", "nt", fasta_string)
    print result_handle.read()
```

Above myfasta is your custom seq file which is provided for internet BLAST

you can later play with result_handle using NCBIXML as you wish to (ie to get top 100,remove duplicates)

Answer (score 5):

Sure can - [the tutorial](http://www.biopython.org/DIST/docs/tutorial/Tutorial.html) explains how to run BLAST locally and with the NCBI and how to parse the results. I'll leave the actual implementation as an exercise for you!

Comment: Ok thanks. Do you also know why I can't import from Bio in python2.6 when I can do it in python2.5?

Comment: why don't you open another question on that?
p.s. you should accept david's answer if you think it is correct.